# How to calculate $v_p[f]$ (directional derivative along tangent vector)

Tags: differential-geometry

I was given the question:

Given the function $f(x,y,z)=x^2y-3z+\pi$ and the vector field $v_p=(e,-\pi,0.5)_{(2,1,3)}$ then calculate $v_p[f]$

I have no idea how to go about doing this and can't seem to find any examples online. Any help would be great

Comment: Please give us your definition of $v_p[f]$!

Comment: This is a single tangent vector at the point $p$, *not* a vector field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that $$v_p[f]=\frac{d}{dt}(f(p+tv_p))|_{t=0}.$$ Here, $$p+tv_p=(2,1,3)+t(e,-\pi,1/2)=(2+et, 1-\pi t, 3+t/2),$$ and $$f(p+tv_p)=(2+et)^2(1-\pi t)-3(3+t/2)+\pi.$$ Now, just take the derivative and evaluate at $t=0.$

Alternatively, use that it equals $$v_1\partial_x f(p)+v_2\partial_y f(p)+v_3\partial_z f(p),$$ where $v_j=(v_p)_j.$ This more general formula follows from the original method via the chain rule, so they're entirely equivalent.

You can find some examples in "Elementary Differential Geometry" by Barrett O'Neil.